# Correct select statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this table called `ps_product_supplier`:

[image]

I want to select all products that has the `product_supplier_reference` occuring more than once and if it occurs on both the main product (`id_product_attribute = 0`) and on a combination.

I tried with this select but I get no result from it:

```
SELECT `id_product_supplier`, `id_product`, `id_product_attribute`,
    `product_supplier_reference`, COUNT(`product_supplier_reference`)
FROM `ps_product_supplier`
GROUP BY `id_product`
HAVING COUNT(`product_supplier_reference`) > 1
    AND `id_product_attribute` = 0
    AND `product_supplier_reference` > 0
```

But as you can see on the image I should get one there since `product_supplier_reference` is same on `id_product_supplier` 1426 and 4210.

Anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all the columns to the group by clause so it works:

```
SELECT `id_product_supplier` , `id_product` , 
       `product_supplier_reference` , COUNT( `product_supplier_reference` )
FROM `ps_product_supplier`
WHERE `product_supplier_reference` >0
GROUP BY `id_product`,`id_product_supplier`,`product_supplier_reference`  
HAVING COUNT( `product_supplier_reference` ) >1
```

Comment: Thanks but i still get a 0 result with this query

Comment: MySQL returnerade ett tomt resultat (dvs inga rader). (Frågan tog 0.0104 sek)
SELECT `id_product_supplier` , `id_product` , `id_product_attribute` , `product_supplier_reference` , COUNT( `product_supplier_reference` )
FROM `ps_product_supplier`
WHERE `id_product_attribute` =0
AND `product_supplier_reference` >0
GROUP BY `id_product` , `id_product_supplier` , `id_product_attribute` , `product_supplier_reference`
HAVING COUNT( `product_supplier_reference` ) >1
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the number of columns listed in the select clause (this will reduce rows) OR add more column names into the group by clause (this increases number of rows) OR use an aggregate function on more columns.

Note that the HAVING clause is designed for evaluating aggregated values and that you can still use the WHERE clause for on-aggregated filtering.

```
## least rows
SELECT `id_product`
       Count(`product_supplier_reference`) 
FROM   `ps_product_supplier` 
WHERE  `id_product_attribute` = 0 
       AND `product_supplier_reference` > 0 
GROUP  BY `id_product`
HAVING Count(`product_supplier_reference`) > 1
```

OR

```
## most rows
SELECT 
       `id_product`, 
       `id_product_attribute`, 
       `product_supplier_reference`, 
       Count(`product_supplier_reference`) 
FROM   `ps_product_supplier` 
WHERE  `id_product_attribute` = 0 
       AND `product_supplier_reference` > 0 
GROUP  BY `id_product`, 
          `id_product_supplier`, 
          `id_product_attribute`, 
          `product_supplier_reference` 
HAVING Count(`product_supplier_reference`) > 1
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Count(`product_supplier_reference`) FROM `ps_product_supplier` WHERE `id_pr' at line 2

Comment: Most rows still get a 0 result

Comment: I  changed both by removing what may have been an incorrect column name. However as i dont know the details of your tables i cannot unscramble all errors. The point of my answer is that in `group by` less columns = less rows & vice versa. But se valid colum names.